# Insert a rectangle at the cursor in the Outlook editor window

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I'm trying to insert a rectangle at the cursor in the Outlook editor window. The code below works in Word.

In Outlook, `oSel.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)` returns -1, which I believe is VBA's way of telling me it is somehow undefined.

Is there another way to get the vertical position of the cursor relative to the document in the current Outlook editor?

```
Public Sub addShape()
    Dim oShp As Word.Shape
    Dim oSel As Word.Selection
    
    Set oSel = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection
    Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.addShape(msoShapeRectangle, getXCoord(oSel), getYCoord(oSel), 50, 25)
    
    With oShp
        .Fill.Visible = False
        .Line.Visible = True
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Line.Weight = 2.25
    End With
    
    Set oShp = Nothing
    Set oSel = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function getXCoord(ByVal oSel As Word.Selection) As Double
    getXCoord = oSel.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
End Function

Private Function getYCoord(ByVal oSel As Word.Selection) As Double
    getYCoord = oSel.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
End Function
```

Comment: "If the selection or range isn't within the screen area, returns – 1"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdinformation?view=word-pia

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, do you know what the docs mean by "screen area"? In Word it works if the selection isn't on-screen. I've made sure the selection is visible in the Outlook editor and it also doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I don't know and you're right I tested and it does work in Word even when the selection is way off screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, it is OK if you use

```
getYCoord = oSel.Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
```

This line fails here unless I have a document open separately in the full Word Application

```
Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.addShape(msoShapeRectangle, getXCoord(oSel), getYCoord(oSel), 50, 25)
```

I think you need something more like

```
Set oShp = oSel.Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes.addShape(msoShapeRectangle, getXCoord(oSel), getYCoord(oSel), 50, 25)
```

or perhaps start by setting

```
Dim oWrd As Word.Application
Set oWrd = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application
Set oSel = oWrd.Selection
Set oShp = oWrd.ActiveDocument.Shapes.addShape(msoShapeRectangle, getXCoord(oSel), getYCoord(oSel), 50, 25)
```

with the following when you're done.

```
Set oWrd = Nothing
```

Comment: I ended up using `getYCoord = oSel.Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)` (getting the info of the range property of the selection, rather than the info of the selection directly)  as well as setting `oWrd` as you recommend at the end of your post. Thank you.